# Create Section With Complex Linq query

Tags: iphone, monotouch.dialog

I'm trying to create a section with linq from xml file.
my xml file build like this:

```
 <root>
    <Item>
       <name>a</name>
       <status>new</status>
    </Item>
    <Item>
       <name>b</name>
       <status>old</status>
    </Item>

 </root>
```

I want to create the section by the following way
if the status tag = "new it will create an entry element
and if its old it will create a stringelement

i thought of something like this

```
new section()
{
    from x in myXdoc.Descendants("Item")
where x.element("Status").value == "new" || x.element("Status").value == "old"

??????

}
```